# Django templates and variable attributes

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and Django templates.
I have a table that I want to display the objects look something like:

```
Object Result:
    Items = [item1,item2]
    Users = [{name='username',item1=3,item2=4},..]
```

The Django template is:

```
<table>
<tr align="center">
    <th>user</th>
    {% for item in result.items %}
        <th>{{item}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

{% for user in result.users %}
    <tr align="center"> 
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        {% for item in result.items %}
            <td>{{ user.item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now the [Django documention](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/#variables) states that when it sees a **.** in variables
It tries several things to get the data, one of which is dictionary lookup which is exactly what I want but doesn't seem to happen...

Comment: This is an elegant solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/781695

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found a "nicer"/"better" solution for getting variables inside
Its not the nicest way, but it works.

You install a custom filter into django which gets the key of your dict as a parameter

To make it work in google app-engine you need to add a file to your main directory,
I called mine *django_hack.py* which contains this little piece of code

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

register = webapp.template.create_template_register()

def hash(h,key):
    if key in h:
        return h[key]
    else:
        return None

register.filter(hash)
```

Now that we have this file, all we need to do is tell the app-engine to use it...
we do that by adding this little line to your main file

```
webapp.template.register_template_library('django_hack')
```

and in your template view add this template instead of the usual code

```
{{ user|hash:item }}
```

And its should work perfectly =)

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming that the part the doesn't work is `{{ user.item }}`.

Django will be trying a dictionary lookup, but using the string `"item"` and not the value of the `item` loop variable.  Django did the same thing when it resolved `{{ user.name  }}` to the `name` attribute of the `user` object, rather than looking for a variable called `name`.

I think you will need to do some preprocessing of the data in your view before you render it in your template.

Answer (score 9):

Or you can use the default django system which is used to resolve attributes in tempaltes like this :

```
from django.template import Variable, VariableDoesNotExist
@register.filter
def hash(object, attr):
    pseudo_context = { 'object' : object }
    try:
        value = Variable('object.%s' % attr).resolve(pseudo_context)
    except VariableDoesNotExist:
        value = None
return value
```

That just works

in your template :

```
{{ user|hash:item }}
```

Comment: I could kiss you

Answer (score 4):

@Dave Webb (i haven't been rated high enough to comment yet)

The dot lookups can be summarized like this: when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

```
* Dictionary lookup (e.e., foo["bar"])
* Attribute lookup (e.g., foo.bar)
* Method call (e.g., foo.bar())
* List-index lookup (e.g., foo[bar])
```

The system uses the first lookup type that works. It’s short-circuit logic.

Answer (score 3):

As a replacement for k,v in user.items on Google App Engine using django templates where user = {'a':1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3}

```
{% for pair in user.items %}
   {% for keyval in pair %} {{ keyval }}{% endfor %}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

a 1
b 2
c 3

pair = (key, value) for each dictionary item.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this:

```
{{ user.item }}
```

be this?

```
{{ item }}
```

there is no user object in the context within that loop....?