# Iterate two dictionaries simultaneously in template

Tags: django

I'm trying to print the values of two dicts simultaneously in a template, like:

```
<td>key</td><td>value from dict1</td><td>value from dict2</td>
```

Both dicts contain the same keys but different values. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom filter to accomplish this. If the keys are the same, first define a custom filter as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/2011147):

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

then you can do the following in your template:

```
{% for key, value1 in dict1.items %}
    <td>Value 1: {{ value1 }}</td>
    <td>Value 2: {{ dict2|get_item:key }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404729/django-template-how-do-i-iterate-two-dictionary-at-same-time) for another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

With a little reorganising in your view you can add as many dictionaries to your template as you want and simultaneously loop through by adding them to a list of dictionaries e.g.

```
dict1 = {'key1':value1, 'key2':value2, 'key3': etc.}
dict2 = {'key1':value1, 'key2':value2, 'key3': etc.}
```

And you want to loop through both lists in your template simultaneously by creating list object. Assuming above lists come from some database objects:

```
datas = []
for item in items:
    # create new dictionary combining values required
    data = {'name':item.name, 'rev':item.rev, 'val':item.val}
    datas.append(data)
```

And then send your list of dictionaries (as you would a filter of django objects) to your template:

```
{% for data in datas %}
    <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.value1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.value2 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```