# Django template table

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 dictionaries data['d1'], data['d2'] and data['d3'].

What i want is the table to look like this, getting the keys from each dictionary and presenting them like:

```
Team 1        |   Team 2       |   Team 3
key 1 from d1 |  key 1 from d2 |  key 1 from d3
key 2 from d1 |  key 2 from d2 |  key 2 from d3
key 3 from d1 |  key 3 from d2 |  key 3 from d3
key 4 from d1 |  key 4 from d2 |  key 4 from d3
```

What i have tryed

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Team 1</th>
        <th>Team 2</th>
        <th>Team 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for key, value in d1.items %}
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for key, value in d2.items %}
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for key, value in d3.items %}
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

or

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Team 1</th>
        <th>Team 2</th>
        <th>Team 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for key, value in d1.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for key, value in d2.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for key, value in d3.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

but it's showing them differently. How can i achieve the above table?

Current table is displayed like this:

```
Stalone Sobont  arda    AAA
Sardina Jhonny  Lala    Vali
LilJon  Scuipy  SSS     Mazare
```

views.py

```
stats = data['scoruri'].copy()
    data['d1'] = {}
    data['d2'] = {}
    data['d3'] = {}

for key, value in stats.copy().items():
    if not data['d1'] or sum(data['d1'].values()) <= sum(data['d2'].values()) and \
                         sum(data['d1'].values()) <= sum(data['d3'].values()):
        name, score = max(stats.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        data['d1'][name] = score
        stats.pop(name, score)
        data['total_1'] = sum(data['d1'].values())
    elif not data['d2'] or sum(data['d2'].values()) <= sum(data['d1'].values()) and \
                           sum(data['d2'].values()) <= sum(data['d3'].values()):
        name, score = max(stats.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        data['d2'][name] = score
        stats.pop(name, score)
        data['total_2'] = sum(data['d2'].values())
    elif not data['d3'] or sum(data['d3'].values()) <= sum(data['d1'].values()) and \
                           sum(data['d3'].values()) <= sum(data['d2'].values()):
        name, score = max(stats.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        data['d3'][name] = score
        stats.pop(name, score)
        data['total_3'] = sum(data['d3'].values())
```

Comment: What is it displaying currently(current table layout)?

Comment: Can you show how you populate d1, d2 and d3 in your view?

Comment: done, look for yourself

Comment: @nik_m can you talk? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is how you can achieve that table:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


d1 = {1: 'Alex', 2: 'Andrei'}
d2 = {1: 'Cristi', 2: 'Ion'}
d3 = {1: 'Sandu', 2: 'Marica'}

d = dict()

d1 = OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items()))
d2 = OrderedDict(sorted(d2.items()))
d3 = OrderedDict(sorted(d3.items()))

d1 = list(d1.items())
d2 = list(d2.items())
d3 = list(d3.items())

d['team_1'] = d1
d['team_2'] = d2
d['team_3'] = d3

d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))


{% for i in d.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.1.0.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all keys of a dict to be printed in a *column* whereas you are printing all keys of a dict in a *row*

You could combine the dicts into a list (in the view) and then iterate over this list in the template.

In the view:

```
data_dicts = [d1,d2,d3]
```

And in the template:

```
<tr>
{% for d in data_dicts %}
    {% for key, value in d.items %}
        <td> {{ key }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Also, [this long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404875/1526703) may also help.

Comment: did you try zipping the dicts?

Comment: uhm.. no i haven't

Comment: Zip is not applicable for dicts.

Comment: @AbijithMg dict.items returns a list, so that can help? Something like: 
`for (k1, v1), (k2, v2), (k3,v3) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items(), d3.items()):
    <tr><td>{{k1}}</td><td>{{k2}}</td>.......</tr>`
(something like that I think)

Comment: zip is not a valid builtin template tag! So the processing has to be done in the view only.

Comment: @AbhijitMg Ah yes, you are right. @NitaAlexandru another solution is to combine the dicts in a list
`d = [d1,d2,d3]` in the view and then iterate over d in the template. I saw a good detailed example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16404875/1526703). Updating the answer

Comment: i tryed it, but it's not giving me the keys from each dictionary

Comment: @NitaAlexandru Updated the answer now to print the key instead of value

Comment: @NitaAlexandru Sorry, as it stands right now, my solution is wrong, it will still not do what you want. I may come back later to think about it, but dont follow the solution above

Comment: hehe, i've noticed, what's now in the answer does what i've tryed before :)

Comment: the list with dictionaries isn't a bad ideea, but how do you get the keys

Comment: Also, if you need the keys in a particular order, need to use an ordered dict, see its not ordered by default

Comment: no, i just want the keys of each dictionary on a column

Comment: @NitaAlexandru If you dont need the dict values at all, how about just sending a list of keys from the view down to the template? `dict.keys()`