# django - how to add counter into {{ }} tag through a template for loop

Tags: for-loop, django-templates

views.py:

```
def main(request):
    users = PUser.objects.filter(ostan=os, shahr=sh, content_id=content)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'users': users})
```

In main.html file:

```
<a href="#">{{ users.0.website }}</a>
.
.
.
<a href="#">{{ users.1.website }}</a>
.
.
.
<a href="#">{{ users.2.website }}</a>
.
.
.
<a href="#">{{ users.3.website }}</a>
```

Now I want to put it through a for loop. So I added this line:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

to views.py, and edited main.html like this:

```
{% for each in numbers %}
    <a href="#">{{ users.0.website }}</a>
{% enfor %}
```

But I dont know how to edit `{{ users.0.website }}` part!

I tried `{{ users.each.website }}` but it didnt print anything. How should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `{{ users.each.website }}` does is that it searches the key `"each"` of type `string` in the `dict` stored in the variable called `users`. So it's not the value in a variable called `each` which is used to look up the value in the `dict` named `users` but the raw value `"each"`.

Unfortunately there's no built-in filter in Django's template language to do what you want but you could implement a template filter for that purpose yourself. See answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067006/accessing-a-dict-by-variable-in-django-templates).

Other than that: Have you remembered to make your variable `numbers` available in the template?

```
def main(request):
    // ...
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'users': users, 'numbers': numbers})
```

... because otherwise the loop will just not be executed at all because `numbers` inside the template is `None`. For your special use case you probably could as well just iterate the collection itself:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <a href="#">{{ user.website }}</a>
{% enfor %}
```

To only show a limited number of entries you can use the [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for) instead of introducing a seperate list of numbers:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if forloop.counter <= 4 %}
        <a href="#">{{ user.website }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes I have added `'numbers': numbers` to the code, just forget to mention in my question. It does not work. And there is need to use indexm because I just want to fetch and print the first four items.

Comment: I will be able to test it myself in a few hours. If no one else has a working solution until then unfortunately I can just think about what might be wrong. I guess the part without the `for` loop (e.g. `users.0.website`) worked fine?

Comment: If you are asking if `{{ users.0.website }}` and `{{ users.1.website }}` and `{{ users.2.website }}` workes fine out of the for loop or not, the answer is yes.

Comment: Until I get home and can test it myself - I edited another possibly working solution into my answer at the end. You could try that as well ... it might actually be cleaner than with the additional list of numbers. :)

Comment: Your next suggestion worked really thank you. Just there is something more... There are some divs with id like this: `<div id="gallery10">` and `<div id="gallery20">`... How can I put them through that for loop? Those numbers should be increased like `10`, `20`, `30` and `40`.

Comment: I just got home and tried it myself. I'm sorry that I've overlooked that, but it's actually quiet simple why it doesn't work. I edited my answer above so you can at least mark it as accepted if you like. :) The thing with the `10, 20, ...` is actually another question so I will just cover this here in the comments: Unfortunally you cannot just multiply two numbers with Django's default template filters. If you want to do that you could use the module [django-mathfilters](https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters) to write something like that: `<div id="gallery{{ forloop.counter|mul:10 }}">`

Comment: I faced with error while installing django-mathfilters, so should look for an other solution. But thank you for your first solution that worked. :)