# Make a django template object iterable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary with a number of characteristics:

```
sort_options = SortedDict([
    ("importance" , ("Importance" , "warning-sign" , "importance")),
    ("effort" , ("Effort" , "wrench" , "effort")),
    ("time_estimate" , ("Time Estimate" , "time" , "time_estimate")),
])
```

I also have a list of actions as a query result.  Each action has these attributes; In my template, I can call {{ action.effort }} or {{ action.time_estimate }} and get a result.

I'm iterating through my sort_options to populate twitter bootstrap icons:

```
{% for key, icon in sort_options.items %}
    <i class="icon-{{ icon.1 }}"></i>
{% endfor %}
```

But I also want to display the action value for each of these attributed.  Essentially, something like:

```
{% for key, icon in sort_options.items %}
    <i class="icon-{{ icon.1 }}"></i>
    {{ action.key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Where key would resolve to "importance" or "effort".  I know this doesn't work. So I was trying to leverage the solution presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948/django-templates-and-variable-attributes).

The solution proposed a template filter:

```
def hash(h,key):
    if key in h:
        return h[key]
    else:
        return None
register.filter(hash)

{{ user|hash:item }}
```

Where the question used a dictionary that looked like so:

```
{'item1': 3, 'name': 'username', 'item2': 4}
```

I tried the following:

```
{% for key, icon in sort_options.items %}
    <i class="icon-{{ icon.1 }}"></i>
    {{ action|hash:key }}
{% endfor %}
```

But got an error:

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: argument of type 'Action' is not iterable
```

I believe this is because the template filter is getting just one attribute of the object (likely the name) as opposed to the whole dictionary:

```
[<Action: Action_one>, <Action: Task_two>...]
```

Is there a way to force the template to pass the full object to the template tag?

Comment: Please make sure that you mean a template tag but not a *template filter*.

Comment: Ignore that other question. Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Apologies for being too hasty with the question.  It is greatly clarified above

Comment: For future reference, mentioning that you're iterating over actions and then iterating over `sort_options` for each `action` would have been handy. Finally, something that looks like `[.., ..]` is a list, not a dictionary. Your "whole dictionary" is better described as a "list of `Action` objects`.

Comment: Can't u just calculate those 'action.key's in your views, and then try sending them as dictionaries to the templates so u won't have to find action.key in your templates ?

Comment: I could, but I would rather not create another dictionary to house data that already exists in action.  Maybe it's simply a matter of preference, but I don't want multiple variables with the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally get it. You want the equivalent of

```
getattr(action, key)
```

in your template. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112236/399367) describes the `getattribute` templatetag you'd need to do so.