# Django templating - accessing dictionary value using a template variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is the data coming from my `views.py`:

```
gradebook_data = {
    'G5A': [...],
    'G5B': [...],
    ...
}

sections = [
    ('G5A': '5-Einstein'),
    ('G5B': '5-Bohr'),
    ...
]
```

In my template, I want to iterate the sections and display gradebook data inside a `for` loop like this...

```
{% for code, section in sections %}
    <td>{{ gradebook_data.code }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work since in Django it tries to do a dictionary lookup for `gradebook_data['code']` when what I want to do is to get `gradebook_data['G5A']`.

Does anybody know a workaround or can point to my mistake? I have spent a whole day just for this already.

This was quite easy to do with PHP's `Twig` templating library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Django templating system you can register a custom filter, which has been documented several times on SO for exactly this purpose.  For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948/django-templates-and-variable-attributes).

Comment: I've thought about making my own filter. I was hoping however, that there is a better way or easier since this is a very common use-case.

Comment: Agreed, but it's really pretty easy if you're comfortable with working  in Django, and once you've done it once the next time will be easy...

Comment: @dashmug in the view function you're really supposed to massage the data more into the form that you later want to consume in the template

Comment: @Anentropic After a lot of researching, that's what I realized. Just felt that it added more complexity. In my case, can you suggest a better structure for the `gradebook_data` above?

Comment: @dashmug why not combine them into a single data structure eg `gradebook_data = {'G5A': ('5-Einstein', [...]), ...}`

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, I guess I have no choice. I wanted to use DRY and not do further massaging but I guess this is the only way.

Comment: Templates should be pretty stupid. Programming logic should always be in your view.